# Certificate Master Public Key with Pairing

Tags: pairings, certificates, abe

I am currently working on CipherText Policy Attribute Based Encryption (CP-ABE) scheme. If we see the scheme, we can notice that the Authority may generate a Master Public Key and a Master Private Key(this last used to generate the user's secret keys).

Now, is there a possibility in order to certificate this Master Public Key generated with Pairing(i.e. using a X.509 certificate or similar)? How can I trust of this MPK?

Comment: Of course you can sign the MPK with some private key to produce a certificate, but are you asking to integrate it into the existing PKI on the web? You can try to find a certificate authority which signs arbitrary data (which this is).

Comment: @Artjom can you give me an example of CA that signs arbitrary data? Can I use OpenSSL?